# Testing Google Wave Gadget outside Google Wave?

Tags: debugging, testing, google-wave

I wonder if there is a tool/framework available that supports testing Google Wave Gadgets outside Google Wave.

I know these two emulators ([1](http://www.hokstad.com/google-wave-gadget-emulator.html) and [2](http://wave.thewe.net/emulator/)), but I still always would have to upload my gadget for every debugging run.

I am looking for a tool that displays the current state, allows to modify the state and to send the state back to the gadget.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing both [1] and [2]...

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

The two emulators you mentioned can be used in the way you described. You just have to download one and run it on a local web server. Then you can develop your gadgets offline, without having to upload them every time you want to test.

Here are links to the source for the gadget emulators:

- http://github.com/vidarh/wave-gadget-emulator
- http://github.com/avital/google-wave-gadget-emulator

Answer (score 2):

There is a Google Wave Gadget API implementation available for Node.js, and this can be run as a standalone service supporting Wave Gadgets running in any web application.

https://github.com/scottbw/wave-node

Answer (score 1):

It isn't 100% easy, but I would recommend setting up your own server on your local machine, for the moment, until someone figures out how or takes the time to wrap such a server into a usable one-click-install tool.

http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth-  Google wave has been open sourced into Apache's WaveInABox: http://www.waveprotocol.org/wave-in-a-box